# Is it possible to put an info on a webpage (but not our)?

Tags: task

I want to put an information in a webpage recurrently by a cron task (or whatever else), each week, but not on my webpage !

For example : value of gold on a trading website, take it every Monday, is it possible ? (I don't want to do that but something similar, the principle is the same)

Comment: Do you have an account with edit permissions on the server of the website that's not yours?  If not, you are effectively asking how to hack data on a website.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that we have no idea what you're trying to achieve. You want some script that displays an augmented webpage on the user's computer?

Comment: @SteveMatthews no !!! I don't want to hack data ! just with the link of the webpage and precise to select the div, I want to copy it ! for exemple here on the page, with the link of the page, I want to select the number of viewed, (which have as class the name of label-key) is it possible ? I'm maybe not clear enough... sorry for my bad english

Comment: is it possible to make a script for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, I guess that you actually want to download data from a web page as a source.

You don't specify which language you are working in but I've personally had some success doing this in .NET using a WebClient.

There is more information about the WebClient [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) but I think to make better use of StackOverflow, you'd be better trying to tighten up your question to include more specifics.